# Bootstrap Panel Headings

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to remove the border that creates the panels Body but having some issues finding it.

Here is the code for my panel:

```
<div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading"> <span class="panel-title"><i class="icon-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Training Team</span><button type="button" name="addProjectMember" class="btn btn-mini pull-right"><i class="icon-plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Project Member</button></div>
        <div name="trainingTeamBody" style="display:none;" class="panel-body">
        <span name="teamError"><br><div class="alert alert-warning"><center>No Project Members Assigned</center></div></span>
           <table name="teamTable" class="table table-hover" style="display: none;">
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th><small>Member</small></th>
                    <th><small>Role</small></th>
                    <th><small>Supervisor</small></th>
                    <th><small>Date Assigned</small></th>
                    <th><small>Who Assigned</small></th>
                    <th><small>Action</small></th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody name="teamTableResults"></tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
     </div>
```

[image]

In the image above, All I would like its the gray bar which would be what I'd consider to be the heading. If there are no results to show, I simply want the bar to appear without the outline of the body.

As a test, I removed the body completely from the code but the border was still there.

Is there a part of the panels CSS that is causing this that I can overwrite?

This is for Panels in Bootstrap 2 which I did by using the following CSS:

```
 panel {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.panel-heading {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: -15px -15px 15px;
  font-size: 17.5px;
  font-weight: 500;      
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

.panel-footer {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 15px -15px -15px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
} 

.panel-primary {
  border-color: #428bca;
}

.panel-primary .panel-heading {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #428bca;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/9ema30gx/2/

`.panel {
    border: 0 !important;
}`

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Whats the best way to make this a class I can add when needed vs having it on every panel? For example, If I have no records in my table, I want just the panel heading. However, If I do have results, it will be a normal panel. I can do the code part, just need to figure out how i can make it a class I can just add when needed to remove the border

Comment: Here's an updated jsfiddle with a custom class: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/9ema30gx/3/

Comment: Hmm, looks like this second one has the border again

Comment: Oh yes.... You just need to change the css: `.newPanel {....}` to `.panel.newPanel {....}`